# Simple Euler scheme for a gradient flow ODE of a convex function.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the gradient flow in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of a (say smooth) function $U:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ which is uniformly convex. i.e for $t\geq 0$ consider

$$x'=-\nabla U(x),~~x(0)=x_0.$$

Consider the following Euler scheme with time step $h$, which using the convexity of the norm $\|\cdot \|^2$ and $U$ we can write as a optimisation problem :

\begin{align*}
  x'(t)&=- \nabla U(x(t)) \\ % a particle descending down an energy potential. 
  \frac{x^{n+1}_h-x^n_h}{h}+ \nabla U(x^{n+1}_h)&=0 \\ % backward euler approximation
    \nabla \Big( \frac{\|x-x^n_h\|^2}{2h} + U(x) \Big) \Big|_{x=x^{n+1}_h}&=0\\ % use definition of grad operator 
     x^{n+1}_h &=\text{argmin}_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \Big\{ \frac{\|x-x^n_h\|^2}{2h} + U(x)  \Big\}\\ 
\end{align*}

$\textbf{Now my question}$ is how can I use the uniform convexity of $U$ to see that the iterates $x^n_h$ are uniformly bounded in $n$? ( Or how can I show that there exists a subsequence $n_k$ for which $x_{n_{k}}$ are uniformly bounded.

Comment: You can rewrite $x_{h}^{n+1} = Prox_{hf}(x_{h}^{n})$ where Prox is the proximal operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_operator. Check https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf or the book "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces"

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve Thats beautiful thanks my friend ! How much does the story change when the norm $\|\cdot\|$ ( of the Hilbert space) is only a $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ ( distance in a metric space )

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $|| \cdot ||$ is only $d(\cdot, \cdot)$. For a Hilbert space  $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$. The results in "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces" assumes there is an inner product $<x|y>$ and the norm and distance are derived from the inner product $||x|| = \sqrt{<x|x>}$ and $d(x,y)=||x-y||$. Example 2.2 - 2.10 in the book gives a list of some inner products. If you are asking what to do if you have a metric space and not a Hilbert space then search for the proximal algorithm in a metric space, i.e., https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.7074.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve 'proximal algorithm in a metric space' - yes this what I meant, cheers mate.